# Need help understanding this error - SyntaxError in Pages#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, haml

Getting an error when working in my local environment, but exact same code pushed to Heroku worked just fine. Any ideas?

Here is what is shown when I try and go to any page in the local environment of the app.

```
 /Users/user/badger/app/views/shared/_navigation.html.haml:211: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
    /Users/user/badger/app/views/shared/_navigation.html.haml:213: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
      end ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
     ^
/Users/user/badger/app/views/shared/_navigation.html.haml:249: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
/Users/user/badger/app/views/shared/_navigation.html.haml:251: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
  end ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
     ^
```

Extracted source (around line #211):

```
208:         :erb
209:           <% if @page and @page.categories_include("About") %>
210:             <%= link_to item.name.capitalize, polymorphic_path(item.navigable), :class => "current" %>
211:           <% else %>
212:             <%= link_to_unless_current item.name.capitalize, polymorphic_path(item.navigable), do
213:               link_to item.name.capitalize, polymorphic_path(item.navigable), :class => "current"
214:             end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current item.name.capitalize, polymorphic_path(item.navigable), do
```

As you can see, you have a comma before `do`. You need to remove this comma.

Answer (score 1):

see below link that how to use `link_to_unless_current`

[link_to_unless_current](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless_current)

Your problem in comma (',') before do

```
<%= link_to_unless_current item.name.capitalize, polymorphic_path(item.navigable), do
```

just that replace with

```
<%= link_to_unless_current item.name.capitalize, polymorphic_path(item.navigable) do
```